# Are i18n string keys considered to be "public API" for the purposes of semantic versioning?

Tags: internationalization, semantic-versioning

I'm maintaining a PHP module that has pretty spotty and outdated i18n coverage, which we're trying to update. In order to get things where they should be, we need to combine some keys (e.g. OrderInformation.ss.QUANTITY and ProductCategoryItem.ss.QUANTITY) and rename others.

In theory, this could cause some sites that were previously translated to revert a few strings upon updating. Does this qualify for a backwards incompatible change under semantic versioning?

Answer (score 0):

> In theory, this could cause some sites that were previously translated to revert a few strings upon updating. Does this qualify for a backwards incompatible change under semantic versioning?

Technically, yes.  If you break your customers, it requires a major version bump.  See [SemVer #8](https://semver.org/#spec-item-8).  The practical answer is how likely is this theoretical breakage?  Theoretically, any change has the potential to break somebody, but we don't bump the major version for every little bug fix, that's what patch is for.

Usually, this question comes up when behavioral changes result that move the needle towards the original intent behind the API, but you have some customers who depend on the original design/implementation flaws.  You have to weigh the costs imposed when some folks take what they think is a non-breaking change, but it isn't; against the cost of having large numbers of customers, not even trying your new major version release, out of fear they'll have a lot of work to do.

If the customer fixes will be trivial, especially if it's not a large fraction of your customer base, you might get away with a minor or patch bump.